# Problem deleting group parameters in amazon aws RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Hello my friends I need your help.
I'm learning to use the AWS console, so I'm using the free version for 12 months.
However, I had a cost for the platform's mysql database, so I deleted the database instance, the automatic backups and also the snapshots, but when I went to delete the group parameters, the error below occurs:

Failed to delete default.mysql8.0: Default DBParameterGroup cannot be deleted: default.mysql8.0 (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDBParameterGroupState; Request ID: cec752fc-6e77-4a42-b38b-c26b079a6e21; Proxy: null).

With this I have the following doubts:
How can I delete this group of parameters?
As I deleted the database instance, automatic backups and snapshots, will I continue to have a cost on the platform?

Thanks

I deleted the DB instance, automatic backups and snapshots.
I tried to delete the group parameters and the error occurred

Answer (score 2):

If you create a DB instance without specifying a DB parameter group, the DB instance will use the default parameter group for the DB engine.

You cannot delete a default parameter group. This is specified in the AWS docs documentation for the [`DeleteDBParameterGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteDBParameterGroup.html) action.

Parameter groups cost no money.